# How to train the same RNN over multiple series?

Tags: lstm, rnn

I have multiple separate time series and would like to train the same LSTM network on them. How to do in this situation? I can't just concatenate timeseries (along time), because I am afraid network will be confused by jumps at the points of concatenation.

How to overcome?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more? Do these time series have the same length? what do you want the RNN to do eventually etc.

Comment: All time series are of different lengths (coincidences are not excluded of course). The goal is to predict next one or more samples on the basis of previous ones.

Comment: Is there a reason for the length variation?, can't resample them to make them have the same number of samples?

Comment: @Amani they represent different periods of observations of some process; if I resample them, I will damage significant data

Comment: LSTM is invariant to 'speed'. Meaning, its strength is detecting patterns whether or not they have the same length. I thing it's worth trying at least.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue. I'm not sure how to train with time-series data from different observations.

Comment: @Dims It's been 5 years but could you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 5):

just re-use

> `model.fit()`

on the fresh datasets using the **already trained** model, simple as that :) !

(given that you do it in Keras)

Comment: What will it do at the beginning? Make previous sample zero?

Comment: if it's part of the same code, the *weights* and the *state* will have the updated values, utilizing the learnt information from the previous training session.

Comment: But won't it have the same effect as if I concatenated series?

Comment: good idea, I guess it will have the similar "jump". Therefore consider  `model.reset_states()` before feeding the new dataset and calling `model.fit()`  :)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, the reason you think cannot concatenate your time series into a one dataset is because of their different length. Depending on your problem, you can handle this issue in multiple manners in preprocessing. But the more common way is to use sequence padding. Preprocessing methods are natively implemented in keras: https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/.

Hope that answers your question.

EDIT 1:

The answer of @pcko1 anwser would work but'll force you into using a batch size of 1, which might give you a much higher convergence time.

Comment: No, length is irrelevant, since I would concatenate series "horizontally", along time.

Comment: Could you reformulate your question to make sure that If I understand correctly, the different periodicities of your time series is your problem ? What I mean is that you have several time series data referring to the same problem but sampled differently ? Am I right ?